# Access a pointer member of an allocated object on the heap that points to another object

Tags: c++

I'm not really sure if the title is correct but i have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class department 
{
    private:
    string name;
    int budget;
    public:
    int NoT; //Number of teachers
    int NoS; //Number of students
    void setName(string nam);
    void setBudget(int budg);
    int getBudget ();
    string getName();
};
class school 
{
    private:
    int YoE;
    string name;
    public:
    department *dpt;
    int NoDpts;
    school();
};
void department::setName(string nam)
{
    name=nam;
}
void department::setBudget(int budg)
{
    budget=budg;
}
int department::getBudget()
{
    return budget;
}
string department::getName()
{
    return name;
}
school::school()
{
    YoE=2000; // Year of estabilishment
    name="Somename";
    NoDpts=37;
}
int main()
{
    string name;
    int budget;
    int budg;
    school *sch;
    sch=new school;
    if (!sch)
    throw("Out of memory");
    sch->dpt=new department[37];
    if (!sch->dpt)
    throw("Out of memory");
    for (int i=0;i<sch->NoDpts;i++)
    {
        cout << "Insert name for department#" << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> name;
        sch->dpt->setName(name);
        cout << "Insert budget for department " << name << ": ";
        cin >> budget;
        sch->dpt->setBudget(budget);
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << "Insert a budget for school: ";
    cin >> budget;
    for (int i=0;i<sch->NoDpts;i++)
    {
        if (budg=sch->dpt->getBudget()>=budget)
        {
            cout << "Name of department is: " << sch->dpt->getName() << endl;
            cout << "Budget of department amounts to: " << sch->dpt->getBudget() << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, i allocated 37 departments, however i don't know how to access them.I mean that in the following line:

```
sch->dpt->setName(name);
```

I merely access the name of the first department (indirectly by using an accessor function),thus overwriting it and getting different results than expected.This happens to other members too such as

```
 sch->dpt->setBudget(budget);
```

So i am simply asking how i can access the members of the rest of the departments.

Comment: `sch->dpt` is a pointer to array so expression `sch->dpt->` will access the first element of the array all the time while you need to access i-th element like this `sch->dpt[i].`

Comment: @VTT Thanks for the input.I have tried this already and get the following compilation error:  base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'department' which really seems strange to me.

Comment: @ John M. That is probably because you wrote `sch->dpt[i]->`

Comment: @VTT Wow,it indeed works!Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Not an answer since VTT already pointed to the error, but since this is C++ you might consider defining `department` not as pointer, but as [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and set it's size in the `school` constructor. In doing so you will avoid the memory leak that is currently in the code. i.e. you allocate `department`with `new[]` but don't  call `delete[]` on it.

Comment: @GertWollny Even though this was a simple program that wasn't meant to do something extrordinary,you are right.I forgot to delete the departments and then the school object.Thanks for reminding me.